# TypeError: def.when is not a function in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I try to get an extra row with colspan (`matColumnDef="table-filter"`) by using the `when` predicate. Fun-fact is, I use the same principle somewhere else in the app (other module) and it just works fine.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="table-filter">
        <td mat-cell [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length" *matCellDef="let data">
            Test
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="some-column">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            Column-Titel
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
            {{ data.someField }}
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let role; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    <!-- Extra row with when predicate -->
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let role; columns: ['table-filter']; when testBoolean;"></tr>
</table>
```

Here, I end up with `TypeError: def.when is not a function`. When I remove the extra row, the table just works fine (`MatTableModule` is of course imported).

Any thoughts?

- `material: ^8.0.2`
- `angular: ^8.1.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... silly me, 5 mins. after posting I figured that I used a boolen for the `when`-predicate - but this needs to be a function with following signature:

```js
  /**
   * Function that should return true if this row template should be used for the provided index
   * and row data. If left undefined, this row will be considered the default row template to use
   * when no other when functions return true for the data.
   * For every row, there must be at least one when function that passes or an undefined to default.
   */
  when: (index: number, rowData: T) => boolean;
```

Comment: so maybe actually finish explaining the fix?